# Creating objects and their reference from text input without losing informations

Tags: python, algorithm, oop, python-3.x, dependencies

Basically what i'm trying to do is to implement a dependency resolving algorithm.

Suppose I have a list like the following:

```
package1:
package2: package1
package3: package1, package2
package4: package1 
package5: package1, package2
```

Basically, `package1` depends just on itself, `package2` depends on `package1`, `package3` depends on 1 and 2 and so on.

What I did until now is the following:

- First, I open the file containing the list
- Second a read each word of the file, putting it on a list
- Third, i enter inside the list, if the elements ends with `:` I create an object with his name(meaning its a package)

Suppose i run the program with the list above, the output is like this:

```
<__main__.Node object at 0x100740ac8>
<__main__.Node object at 0x100740b00>
None
<__main__.Node object at 0x100740ac8>
None
None
<__main__.Node object at 0x100740b00>
None
<__main__.Node object at 0x100740ac8>
None
None
```

The part where i create new packages object works fine, since as we can see there are objects, but the part where i reference the dependency with the main package fails, since it displays `None`, which is not correct.

In order to be correct, the output should be like the following

```
package1
package2
package1
package3
package1
package2
package4
package1
package5
package1
package2
```

I think that were i'm making mistakes is this part:

```
f = open('data.txt','r')


text = []
resolved = []
unresolved = []

for line in f.readlines():
    for char in line.split():
        text.append(char)



class Node:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.edges = []

    def addEdge(self, node):
        self.edges.append(node)

    def dep_resolve(self, resolved, unresolved):
        unresolved.append(self)
        print (self.name)
        for edge in self.edges:
            if edge not in resolved:
                if edge in unresolved:
                    raise Exception('Circular')
                edge.dep_resolve(resolved, unresolved)
        resolved.append(self)
        unresolved.remove(self)

global flag
for i in range(len(text)):
    if text[i].endswith(':'):
        newstr = text[i].replace(':', '')
        newstr = Node(newstr)
        flag = newstr
        print(flag.name)

    else:
        flag.addEdge(text[i])
        print(flag.addEdge(text[i]))
```

and in particular the `else` where i reference to an object of type `str` while i should reference to an object of type `Node` but i have no idea how to fix it.

If you need more of the code i will put it

Comment: You seem to have at least two problems here. First, you're printing out `<__main__.Node object at 0x100740ac8>` where you wanted `package1`, presumably because you're either missing a `__str__` or `__repr__` method or forgot a `.name` attribution somewhere. Second, you're printing out `None` where you wanted the second `package`, presumably because some references are wrong. Which one do you want help with?

Comment: Second one! I know i'm printing ```<__main__.Node object at 0x100740ac8>``` but it was just to show that are objects, so if you could help me with the second problem i will be grateful!

Comment: Anyway, instead of just giving us a fragment of code and leaving us to guess at the inputs and the rest of the context, please give us a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)—something we can just run and see what's wrong. This could just mean a 6-line stripped-down `None` class and a value for the `text` list and the stuff about `flag` stripped out because it's not relevant, but it's hard to guess.

Comment: @abarnert The input is as before, i a just put the whole code so that is easier to understand were i'm making a mistake!
Thanks for your time!

Comment: The whole code is still not a minimal, complete, verifiable example, because it's definitely not minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand how your code is supposed to work, because there are many pieces that don't make sense. However, I can explain this much:

The reason you're printing out `None` is this:

```
flag.addEdge(text[i])
print(flag.addEdge(text[i]))
```

The first calls `addEdge`.

The second calls `addEdge` again, which seems wrong, and `print`s its return value. Because it doesn't have a `return` statement, that value is `None`.

I think what you wanted was:

```
flag.addEdge(text[i])
print(text[i])
```

Meanwhile:

> … i reference to an object of type str while i should reference to an object of type `Node` but i have no idea how to fix it

If you just want to create a `Node` object here, you do it the same way you did it a few lines earlier:

```
new_node = Node(text[i])
flag.addEdge(new_node)
print(new_node)
```

I'm not sure what that will get you, but it will solve the problem you described.

Answer (score 0):

You use `nexstr` inconsistently.

Look at this part:

```
newstr = text[i].replace(':', '')
newstr = Node(newstr)
flag = newstr
print(flag.name)
```

With `newstr = text[i].replace(':', '')` you actually assign `newstr = ''`.
Then you instantiate Node with empty string `''` as parameter and again assign it to `newstr`, so `newstr` refers to an object (the Node class), not a string any more.
Than you reassign this object to `flag`

First, make sure `newstr` really contains what you want.
Then

```
flag = Node(newstr)
print(flag.name)
```

Should work (I haven't tested it, though)